# Perl windows telnet session end

Tags: perl, telnet

I have written Perl script to automate my work using telnet to connect to windows and start server.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Net::Telnet;

$telnet = new Net::Telnet ( Timeout=>30, Errmode=>'die');
$telnet->open('ip');
$telnet->waitfor('/login: $/i');
$telnet->print('admin');
$telnet->waitfor('/password: $/i');
$telnet->print('password');
$telnet->waitfor('/\C:\\\\Documents and Settings\\\\Administrator/');
$telnet->print('start server');
$telnet->close();
```

When the program ends, server again returns back to not running state.
In Unix, this works well.

Comment: What do you mean by 'in Unix, this works well'? You mean when the script is executed on a Unix machine or when you connect to a Unix machine?

Comment: Yes... when i run the same code in unix, the sever keep running when the script ends.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the Microsoft Telnet Server beware that there are issues with encoding and control characters.

From the [documentation of Net::Telnet](http://search.cpan.org/~jrogers/Net-Telnet-3.03/lib/Net/Telnet.pm#Connecting_to_a_Remote_MS-Windows_Machine)

> Connecting to a Remote MS-Windows Machine
>
> By default MS-Windows doesn't come with a TELNET server. However third
>   party TELNET servers are available. Unfortunately many of these
>   servers falsely claim to be a TELNET server. This is especially true
>   of the so-called "Microsoft Telnet Server" that comes installed with
>   some newer versions MS-Windows.
>
> When a TELNET server first accepts a connection, it must use the ASCII
>   control characters carriage-return and line-feed to start a new line
>   (see RFC854). A server like the "Microsoft Telnet Server" that doesn't
>   do this, isn't a TELNET server. These servers send ANSI terminal
>   escape sequences to position to a column on a subsequent line and to
>   even position while writing characters that are adjacent to each
>   other. Worse, when sending output these servers resend previously sent
>   command output in a misguided attempt to display an entire terminal
>   screen.
>
> Connecting Net::Telnet to one of these false TELNET servers makes your
>   job of parsing command output very difficult. It's better to replace a
>   false TELNET server with a real TELNET server. The better TELNET
>   servers for MS-Windows allow you to avoid the ANSI escapes by turning
>   off something some of them call console mode.

Comment: so there is no other way to start server of remote machine?? windows?

Comment: After $telnet->close(); the server went back to old state(not running).
I want the server to be running, even the program ends.